# Binding a TextBlock back to ListBoxItem ItemSource

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, styles, listboxitem

I have a ListBoxItem Style that I am trying to modify so that it will show character ellipsis when the list box is made to small. To do that I've had to get rid of the ContentPresenter in our code and replace it with a TextBlock. The ListBoxes that this is applied to are all bound via the ItemSource property.

Here is my code.

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <!-- Before this used to be ContentPresenter but I switched it to TextBlock to get it the TextTrimming property. I can't find the right way to bind the data though.-->
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="HoverRectangle"
                               Stroke="{StaticResource Gold}"
                               StrokeDashCap="Square"
                               StrokeThickness="0"
                               SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="KeyboardFocusRectangle"
                               Height="Auto"
                               SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                               Stroke="{StaticResource BrightBlue}"
                               StrokeDashCap="Square"
                               StrokeThickness="0" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                     <!-- Bunch of Triggers in here -->
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My current TextBlock Text binding (Text="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}") is not working.  What should the binding be in order to work correctly?

Comment: You've buried your "question" in amongst your code - I suggest you edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only reasonable choice here is to assume the data context of the ListBoxItem is a string, or can be displayed as such:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" .../>
```

Comment: That didnt actually fix my problem but it did provide me with information that pointed me in the right direction. I should have been looking into creating a DataTemplate for it. I did that and it solved the problem. Thank you!